# Accionar controller ao atualizar a página

Tags: php, codeigniter

Boas, estou a construir uma dashboard onde quero que ,ao fazer refresh à minha página, ela accione o controlador 'Notificacoes' que me irá retornar valores provenientes de uma base de dados.

A minha duvida é, como é que eu consigo accionar o controller ao fazer o refresh da página? A minha ideia é usar o evento 'onload' mas não sei como faço a função para accionar o controller.

Se alguém me puder ajudar agradecia!

Comment: A responsabilidade do controlador é responder uma requisição HTTP. Se quer acioná-lo, basta enviar uma requisição para a URL que ele terá; pode fazer isso com requisições assíncronas no navegador.

Comment: Portanto, ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Se bem entendi, acho que deseja o seguinte:

Utilizando **jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {

    notificacoes();

   });

 function notificacoes(){

    $.post("<?=base_url('notificacoes/buscar')?>",
            {},
            function(data){

              //faça o que quiser aqui

            }
    );
 }

</script>
```